# Консоль выдает в Eclipce: TERM environment variable not set

Tags: c++, linux, семафоры

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <termios.h>
#define KEY 1234

union semun
{
    int              val;    /* Value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;    /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short  *array;  /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
    struct seminfo  *__buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_INFO*/
};

static int WaitSemaphore(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf semBuf;
    semBuf.sem_num = sem_num;
    semBuf.sem_op = -1;
    semBuf.sem_flg = IPC_NOWAIT;

    if(semop(sem_id, &semBuf, 1) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't done semaphore P: ";
        perror("semop");
        std::cout << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return (1);
}

static int ReleaseSemaphore(int sem_id, int sem_num)
{
    struct sembuf semBuf;
    semBuf.sem_num = sem_num;
    semBuf.sem_op = 1;
    semBuf.sem_flg = IPC_NOWAIT;

    if(semop(sem_id, &semBuf, 1) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't done semaphore V: ";
        perror("semop");
        std::cout << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return (1);
}

int main()
{
    static int semId;
    int dataProcessed;
    int filePipes[2];
    char someData[100];
    char buffer[BUFSIZ + 1];
    pid_t forkResult;

    system("clear");

    union semun semopts;
    semopts.val = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        if (semctl(semId, i, SETVAL, 0) == -1)
            return(0);

    if((semId = semget((key_t)KEY, 0, 0666)) < 0)
        {
            perror("semget");
            exit(-1);
        }

    while(true)
    {
        if(pipe(filePipes) == 0)
        {
            forkResult = fork();

            if(forkResult == (pid_t)-1)
            {
                std::cout << "Fork failure: " << stderr;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if(forkResult == 0) //client
            {
                WaitSemaphore(semId, 0);
                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); //заполнить нулями
                dataProcessed = read(filePipes[0], buffer, BUFSIZ);



                std::cout << "Client: ";

                for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZ + 1; i++)
                {

                    std::cout << buffer[i];
                }
                sleep(1);
                //std::cout << "Process ID:" << getpid() << " read " << dataProcessed << " bytes" << std::endl;
                ReleaseSemaphore(semId, 1);
            }

            else //server
            {
                ReleaseSemaphore(semId, 0);
                std::cout << "\nServer: ";
                std::cin >> someData;
                dataProcessed = write(filePipes[1], someData, strlen(someData));
                //std::cout << "Process ID:" << getpid() << " wrote " << dataProcessed << " bytes" << std::endl;
                WaitSemaphore(semId, 1);

            }
        }
    }

    semctl(semId, 0, IPC_RMID, 0);
    waitpid(forkResult, NULL, 0);
    system("clear");
    return 0;
}
```

ЗАДАНИЕ:
Необходимо создать два процесса: клиентский и серверный. Серверный процесс ждет ввода пользователем текстовой строки и по нажатию клавиши Enter инициируются следующие действия:
клиентский процесс ожидает уведомления о том, что серверный процесс готов начать передачу данных (синхронизация);
серверный процесс передает полученную от пользователя строку клиентскому процессу, используя либо каналы, либо сегменты разделяемой памяти / файловые проекции;
клиентский процесс принимает строку и выводит ее на экран;
серверный процесс ожидает уведомления от клиентского процесса об успешном получении строки;
серверный процесс вновь ожидает ввода строки пользователем и т.д.
В данной работе продолжается освоение синхронизации процессов. Уведомление процессов должно производиться посредством семафоров.

У меня какая-то маленькая ошибочка, не могу понять где! Уже 2 дня голову ломаю! Вылазит только TERM environment variable not set. Хотя до этого все работало, кроме семафоров! Может я семафоры неправильно написал, но я только учусь и не могу сходу понять столь сложные вещи. Тем более работу с несколькими семафорами в Linux.

Comment: Сдается мне, проблема не в коде, а в eclipse. Попробуйте новый проект создать с пустой main для проверки.

Comment: другие проекты запускаются без проблем((( попробую перезагрузиться

Comment: @Dzmitry А вы переменную `TERM` то пробовали поставить в какое нибудь подходящее значение перед запуском `eclipse`. т.е. `export TERM=linux`, например. это в консоли. Ваше приложение вызывает `clear`, системный, а он наверняка что бы узнать как очистить ваш терминал пытается получить значение переменной окружения `TERM`. Хотя я удивлен почему она у вас не задана, большинство способов какими можно подключится к linux формируют нормальный `TERM`